# If $H \triangleleft G$ is a normal subgroup of a polycyclic $G$, then $G/H$ is polycyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> $G$ is polycyclic if there is a chain of subgroups $$ \{e\}=G_0 \triangleleft G_1\triangleleft G_2 \ldots G_n=G$$
>   and $G_i/G_{i-1}$ is cyclic. If  $H \triangleleft G$ is a normal subgroup of a polycyclic $G$, show $G/H$ is polycyclic.

For this problem I was tempted to show that for the sequence $G_1/ G_0\subseteq G_2/G_1 \ldots \subseteq G/H$ we have $G_{i+1}/G_i \triangleleft G_{i+2}/G_{i+1}$ so it satisfies the first property. But I cannot prove this claim is true. I doubt if this is the right move. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the quotient of the entire chain by $H$ to get $$\overline{G_0} \triangleleft \overline{G_1} \triangleleft \dots \triangleleft \overline{G_n} = G/H$$

where $\overline{G_i} = G_i H / H$.  It is easy to check that $\overline{G_i}$ is normal in $\overline{G_{i+1}}$, and the quotients are cyclic.

Comment: did you mean $\overline{G_i}=G_i/H$?

Comment: @Lewis  No.  You cannot write $G_i / H$ because you do not know that $H$ is contained in $G_i$.  In order to take the quotient, you must "force" the containment by multiplying by $H$ first, and then take the quotient: $\overline{G_i} = G_i H / H$.

Comment: Thank you! From the definition I could easily see that $\overline{G_{i+1}}/ \overline{G_i}$ is cyclic. But I am not sure how to show that $\overline{G_i}$ is normal in $\overline{G_{i+1}}$. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Note that $\overline{G_{i+1}}$ is generated by all $\overline{g}$ for $g \in G_{i+1}$.  Show that any $g \in G_{i+1}$ conjugates $G_i H$ to itself.

Comment: Using the fact that $H$ is normal in $G$ and $G_i$ in $G_{i+1}$, I get $g_{i+1}hG_iH=G_iHg_{i+1}h$. So $G_iH$ is normal in $G_{i+1}H$. Is this correct? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\pi:G\rightarrow G/N$ be the quotient map. Then 
$$
1=\pi(G_0)\triangleleft \pi(G_1)\triangleleft \pi(G_2) \ldots \pi(G_n)=G/N
$$
is a subnormal series with cyclic quotients.
Hence $G/N$ is polycyclic.